# When reverse engineering code to make a web page plugin, how can I find what function is called when a certain element receives an event?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering

I run into this problem quite often when I decide to try tinkering with a 3rd party site for a browser plugin, let's say I want to make a simple auto-play plugin for a video site that doesn't have an autoplay feature. There's a UI element that I know triggers their internal function for playing the video, but I dont know how to identify that function by inspecting the element in the console.

What tricks / methods can I use to be able to trigger that function manually without the user actually clicking the element?

Comment: Can't you just use `element.play()`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge .play() would potentially fail to trigger other essential operations that the application may normally trigger with an organic click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that clicking a button or an element somewhere results in the video playing, often it'll be simple enough to just call `.click()` on that button.

With the mouse hovered over the element with the functionality, right click and Inspect at that point, and the Elements panel of the developer console should bring you to the element the mouse is over. Figure out a selector or a process to uniquely identify the element, and then `.click()` it, eg

```
document.querySelector('.video-container .play-button').click();
```

You also may need to wait for the video container / play button to be created in the DOM first, in which case you can use `MutationObserver` or a `setInterval` to wait for the site to be ready.

An alternative, trickier method is to, when inspecting the element, go to the Event Listeners panel, and look for listeners attached to click / mousedown (etc) events. Sometimes, these functions are callable from the global scope, in which case you can call those functions directly instead of clicking the element.

If the function *isn't* callable from the global scope, a hacky method to get a reference to it anyway is to monkeypatch `addEventListener` before the page loads, listen for when the listener you want gets attached, and then call the function passed. (But the earlier methods are much simpler and preferable when possible)

Comment: I had tried `element.onclick()` but never knew about `element.click()`! This works great. I'm slow.

Comment: This works with some buttons, but I've gone through like 20 wrappers on a page triggering `.click()` trying to figure out which element the play / pause functionality is attached to (the whole video space can be clicked to trigger the event but right clicking is disabled on all elements in the page, so its hard to identify)

Comment: is it possible that `.click()` would not work when a mousedown, mouseup series of events is used in the listener rather than `onclick`?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome dev tools I think you can add a breakpoint for when an event is fired which might allow you to find the function that the 3rd party calls or you could simulate the click event using this code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events):

```js
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox'); 
  var cancelled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}
```

For more information see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).

Comment: While the other answer told me what I asked: How to trigger the click, this answer is equally important - in an application Im looking at now, the rewind and fastforward icons work when click is triggered on them, but the play icon does not work. Obviously the listener is on the whole video, but which one of the 20-30 different elements that overlay the video? Thats hard to find, perhaps this method can help